# How to adjust view layout based on text size

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a view that I want to layout in either a large format or compact format depending on the length of text in a textview like so:

[image: View layout]

What is the best way to achieve this?

I am thinking I will need to measure the length of the text and the controls and get the available space to see if they would fit on one line. If they will then use a compact layout otherwise use the large layout.

Is this the right approach or is there a way to achieve this with a single layout?

Comment: you want that rectangle as you textview background right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout you require is something called FlowLayout. But android SDK doesn't have such a layout support currently. There are nice 3rd party libraries available & one of them is [FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout).

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.wefika:flowlayout:0.4.1'
```

In your layout :

```
<com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start|top">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum" />

</com.wefika.flowlayout.FlowLayout>
```

Comment: This looks like it has potential. I have my controls in a linear layout. They are sticking to the left hard up against the title. Is there any way to make them stick to the right side? Setting gravity on the linear layout had no affect.

Comment: @zorro2b The child elements of FlowLayout can be arranged to right side by setting android:gravity="right|top" to FlowLayout

Comment: That's not quite what I want as the title needs to be aligned to the left.

Comment: can you share layout code you are trying with this FlowLayout??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118512/discussion-between-zorro2b-and-sjy).

Answer (score 0):

Put both in a LinearLayout and set its orientation programically in java file like this

`LinearLayout layout = /* ... */;
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);`

Set Horizonatal if you want compact and set vertical if you want large one.
and put condition based on the width you get from below code

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make user set texts for all your textViews and after use something like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
if(layout.getWidth()/2<Title.getWidth()){
p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.Title);

controls.setLayoutParams(p);
}else{
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.Title);
controls.setLayoutParams(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called a FlowLayout. Google it for multiple libraries that support it.